# Posting messages in Facebook groups causes message to be seen by all friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

When I post something in one group, it actually not only visible to that group but also to all my friends in friends list. More or like posting myself in a wall.

Please tell me what settings have to be changed to make texts visible to group members only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it is currently an Open group, but you want it to be Closed or Secret.  This setting can be [changed](https://www.facebook.com/help?faq=286027304749263) by a group admin, if the group has less than 250 members.